# removing Index.php from URL from CodeIgniter

Tags: php, windows, apache, codeigniter-3

hi I know this question has been asked many times but I tried every thing I can think of
i want to call controller function like this
http://127.0.0.1/example/controller/function
with out the index.php
http://127.0.0.1/example/index.php/controller/function
my environment is
windows 10
apache 2.4
php 7.4
using CodeIgniter 3

1-apache rewrite_module is on I checked it it on  the loaded modules

2-CI config as follow

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

3- my root .htaccess as follow

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php/page/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

4- i changed all AllowOverride from None to All in apache httpd.conf

and it still not working
btw it work on my other machine fine with this same configuration
any help or idea will be much appreciated
thanks

Comment: please, make it a habit to see documentation,
in the Ci documentation is already explained,
please go to [this link](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html)

Comment: thanks , i already did read the documentation i did every thing they mentioned but for some reason it still not working so i asked if there is any thing else i can do, thank you

Comment: take a look at this [link](https://php5.racoontech.my.id/ci/main/index), do you want like this?